# How to download apollo schema using gradle type:exec

Tags: java, gradle, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I want to know how to execute the "apollo schema:download" command in gradle so I don't have to generate the schema through the command line every-time it has been updated.

I've search all over stackoverflow for anything similar and I can't seem to find a thing. This is what I ran far:

```
//this will list all the files in my directory -- this works
task createSchema(type:Exec){
  commandLine 'ls'
}

//but what i want to do is this -- this doesn't work
task createSchema(type:Exec){
  commandLine 'apollo schema:download src/main/graphql/schema.json --endpoint="http://myendpoint.com" --header="myHeader: header"'
}
```

What I expected:

✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✔ Saving schema to src/main/graphql/schema.json

What I got:

```
Cause: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A github issue for the apollo android repository explaining my problem: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/683

How I solved it:

```
    import com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.ApolloSchemaIntrospectionTask

class ApolloIntrospect extends ApolloSchemaIntrospectionTask {}

task introspectSchema(type: ApolloIntrospect) {
    url = "http://api.githunt.com/graphql"
    output = project.projectDir.absolutePath + 'schema.json'
}
```

The schema must not be present in the src/main/graphql directory or an error will be thrown.